# Download and print reddit page which can be redirected to file

Tags: python

I wanted to save the a reddit thread to a `.org` file. I noticed that it is easier to use pandoc to convert `.md` to `.org` (esp when it comes to list items).

My code prints the output to the screen which can be redirected to the required file.

Process is as follows.

```
python reddit_download.py -u <url_to_download> > myfile.md
pandoc -s myfile.md -o myfile.org
```

My script

`reddit_config.py`

```py
class Config:
    client_id = 'myID'
    client_secret = 'mySecret'
    password = 'my_password'
    user_agent = 'my_user_agent'
    username = 'my_username'
```

`reddit_download.py`

```py
import argparse
import praw
from reddit_config import Config


def reddit():
    red = praw.Reddit(client_id=Config.client_id,
                      client_secret=Config.client_secret,
                      user_agent=Config.user_agent,
                      username=Config.username,
                      password=Config.password)
    return red


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--url', required=True, help='URL required', dest='url')
    return parser


def get_full_page(reddit_instance, url):
    post = reddit_instance.submission(url=url)

    page = [{
        # content of post
        "id": post.id,
        "parent": post.id,
        "body": post.selftext,
        "author": post.author.name,
        "ups": post.ups,
        "title": post.title
    }]

    # all comments/replies
    list_of_comments = post.comments.list()
    list_of_comments_with_desired_attributes = [{
            "id": comment.id,
            "parent": comment.parent_id.replace('t1_', '').replace('t3_', ''),
            "body": comment.body,
            "author": comment.author.name,
            "ups": comment.ups
        }
        for comment in list_of_comments
    ]

    page += list_of_comments_with_desired_attributes

    return page


def lookup(loc):
    comment_lookup = dict()
    for comment in loc:
        comment_id = comment["id"]
        if comment_id != comment["parent"]:
            parent_id = comment["parent"]
            children = comment_lookup.get(parent_id)
            if not children:
                children = comment_lookup[parent_id] = list()
            children.append(comment.copy())
        else:
            parent = comment.copy()
    return parent, comment_lookup


def hierarchy(parent_element, comment_lookup):
    parents = comment_lookup.get(parent_element["id"], list())
    for parent in parents:
        hierarchy(parent, comment_lookup)
    if parents:
        parent_element['children'] = parents
    return parent_element


def org(post_dict, parent_id, visited=None, depth=1):
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    visited.add(parent_id)
    print('#'*depth, post_dict.get('ups'), post_dict.get('author'), end='\n\n')
    title = post_dict.get('title')
    if title is not None:
        print(post_dict.get('title', ''), end='\n\n')
    print(post_dict.get('body'), end='\n\n')
    children = post_dict.get('children')
    if children is not None:
        for child in children:
            if child.get('id') not in visited:
                org(child, child.get('id'), visited, depth+1)
    return ''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = parse_args()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    reddit = reddit()
    page = get_full_page(reddit, args.url)
    parent, comment_lookup = lookup(page)
    post = hierarchy(parent, comment_lookup)
    post_id = post.get('id')
    org(post, post_id)
```

Is there a way to improve this code? I am confused how to remove the print statements and build a string to write to a file. Effectively I don't have to redirect the output in shell to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Configuration

Your `reddit_config.Config` needs to be changed so that, rather than hard-coded strings in a Python module, these are externalized to environment variables, or a permissions-restricted configuration file.

### List construction alternatives

There are some alternatives to your concatenate-and-return in `get_full_page`: you can either make this a generator function -

```
    yield {
        # content of post
        "id": post.id,
        "parent": post.id,
        "body": post.selftext,
        "author": post.author.name,
        "ups": post.ups,
        "title": post.title
    }
    # ...
    yield from (
        {
            "id": comment.id,
            "parent": comment.parent_id.replace('t1_', '').replace('t3_', ''),
            "body": comment.body,
            "author": comment.author.name,
            "ups": comment.ups
        }
        for comment in list_of_comments
    )
```

or you can star-expand -

```
return [
    {
        # content of post
        "id": post.id,
        "parent": post.id,
        "body": post.selftext,
        "author": post.author.name,
        "ups": post.ups,
        "title": post.title
    },
    *(
        {
            "id": comment.id,
            "parent": comment.parent_id.replace('t1_', '').replace('t3_', ''),
            "body": comment.body,
            "author": comment.author.name,
            "ups": comment.ups
        }
        for comment in list_of_comments
    ),
]
```

### Truthy lists

Your

```
if not children
```

is too broad. This statement will pass if `children == []`, which it doesn't need to - instead, consider

```
if children is None:
```

or better yet, replace this whole mechanism with a `defaultdict`.

### Unused return

`org()` returns `''`, which both has no meaning and is unused, so you can just delete that line.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.